# Og Image is not working in facebook share in php

Tags: php, image, facebook

I am working with Php, Actually i want that whenever i copy url of my current page and paste in
facebook (as create new post) then Image/Thumbnail should display in facebook wall,how can i do this ?
I tried with following code,How can i fix this ? Thank you in advance.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg
" />
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to share on Facebook?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing the line break?

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```